# How do I pass an ArrayList of Objects from my main method to a method in another class (to then be sorted by a specific property)

Tags: java, class, arraylist, parameter-passing

Here's my main method

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<TutorialWebsite> tutorial = new ArrayList<>();

        File tutorialsFile = null;
        Scanner infile = null;

        try {
            tutorialsFile = new File("Tutorials.txt");
            infile = new Scanner(tutorialsFile);

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(infile.hasNext()){
            TutorialWebsite newTut = new TutorialWebsite();

            newTut.setLanguageName(infile.nextLine());
            newTut.setWebsiteDescription(infile.nextLine());
            newTut.setWebsiteUrl(infile.nextLine());

            tutorial.add(newTut);
        }
```

What I would like to do is send tutorial, after fully loaded, to this method which is located in the TutorialWebsite class

```
public void doInsertionSort(ArrayList<TutorialWebsite> input){
        int i, j;
        String iKey, jKey;

        for (i = 1; i < input.size(); i++){
            iKey = input.get(i).getLanguageName();
            j = i-1;
            while (i >= 0) {
                jKey = input.get(j).getLanguageName();
                if(iKey.compareTo(jKey) > 0){
                        break;
                }
                input.set(i, input.get(i+1));
                i++;
            }
            iKey = input.get(i+1).getLanguageName();
        }
    }
```

I've tried doInsertionSort(tutorial); but I just get a "cannot find symbol" error and tutorial.doInsertionSort(); and same error. I'm really not sure how else I would pass it on. This is my first time working with ArrayLists (let alone objects of ArrayLists) and I'm having trouble finding my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Make `doInsertionSort` a `static` method and call it with `TutorialWebsite.doInsertionSort(tutorial);`.
2. Create a TutorialWebsite object and call the method `TutorialWebsite tw = new TutorialWebsite(...); tw.doInsertionSort(tutorial);`.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's quite a bit simpler than what I tihnk I was fiding when I attempted searching for this issue. Much appreciated!